# Storing email (extra/non-essential) headers in MySQL as JSON properly

Tags: mysql, json, email

So I'm building an email module in to my software. Beyond essential headers I've decided to simply keep the `$headers` array and store it in a `TEXT` column called *headers*. Basically the only time this JSON stored data will be retrieved is when someone does an AJAX request to look at the extended headers (not loaded by default). I'll pull it from MySQL, convert the JSON to a PHP array and iterate over each of the header fields. So in other words I won't be selectively choosing any parts of the array inside of the JSON (inside of the database), merely as a string to be handled by PHP. In this case is using `TEXT` data type appropriate? I'm also open to other advice.

Comment: Sure, that's fine. You could also `serialize` and `unserialize` the array instead of using JSON; I don't think there's any reason to convert it to a JavaScript object if it's only ever going to be used in PHP.

Comment: I totally forgot about `serialize` and that makes more sense, post it as an answer and I'll except it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, that's fine. You could also `serialize` and `unserialize` the array instead of using JSON; I don't think there's any reason to convert it to a JavaScript object if it's only ever going to be used in PHP.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully anyone else looking for JSON will also remember (or learn about) using `serialize` instead.